# Deleted Default Permission Level

Tags: permissions

I accidentally deleted the default "Design" permission level from a team site. If I make a new Design level with the same permissions, will it work just like the default, or will some functionality be lost?

(Sharepoint 2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work the same. Just copy it from any other site and assign the same. The permission will behave the same if you assign it to anyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a permission level on the top level site of a site collection. You can find this by going to Site Settings -> Site Permissions -> Permission Levels (in Permissions tab) -> Add a Permission Level. From here you can recreate a Contribute group.

Here's an article that has the default permissions for each level as well if you want to exactly recreate the Design group.

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Permission-levels-and-permissions-in-SharePoint-2007-49d456eb-d3c8-4402-86b1-deb911224afb?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE

Answer (score 1):

The functionality will be the same.

SharePoint's permission levels are a pre-defined group of permissions for several functionalities within a site. The **Design**-level has the following permissions:

> Create lists and document libraries, edit pages and apply themes, borders, and style sheets on the site. There is no SharePoint group that is assigned this permission level automatically.

When re-creating the permission level, you need to add the following permissions for it (assuming you want to mimic the built-in permission level):

**Site permissions and permission levels**

- Add and Customize Pages
- Apply Themes and Borders
- Apply Style Sheets
- Browse Directories
- Use Self-Service Site Creation
- View Pages
- Browse User Information
- Use Remote Interfaces
- Use Client Integration Features
- Open
- Edit Personal User Information

**List permissions and permission levels**

*(In a nutshell, every available permission)*

- Manage Lists
- Override Check-Out
- Add Items
- Edit Items
- Delete Items
- View Items
- Approve Items
- Open Items
- View Versions
- Delete Versions
- Create Alerts
- View Application Pages

**Personal permissions and permission levels**

*(In a nutshell, every available permission)*

- Manage Personal Views
- Add/Remove Private Web Parts
- Update Personal Web Parts

([Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848))